# функции hold on, hold off

Tags: matlab

Есть код программы который обрабатывает видео,
не пойму к какой функции привязать после hold off чтобы обрабатывался кадр

---

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('No.avi');
depVideoPlayer = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer(15);
writer = vision.VideoFileWriter('Result2.avi');

k = 0;
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
      frame1 = step(videoFReader);
      step(depVideoPlayer, frame1);
      k = k+1;
      if (k >= 1) && (k < 500);
       Ib=rgb2gray(frame1);
       G=fspecial('average', 11)
       filt = imfilter(Ib,G,'symmetric');
         F1=im2double(filt); 


I=Ib-filt; 

imshow(I);  

k=0.95; 

p=k*max(I(:)); 

[x, y]=size(I);% определение размера результирующего изображения  свертки 

num=numel(I);%Возвращает количество элементов num в массиве I 

for n=1:num 

if I(n)>p F(n)=255; 

else F(n)=0; 

end 

end 

F; 

bw=reshape(F,[x,y]);% Возвращает матрицу x на y 

  F2=uint8(bw); 


 % выводит на экран бинарный сигнал объекта 

S=bwarea(bw(:,:,1))

s = regionprops(F2,'centroid');
centroids = cat(1,s.Centroid);


hold on
F4= (geoplot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'b+'));

hold off

frame2 = F4-1;
          step(writer, frame2); 

      else end;
end;
release(videoFReader);
release(depVideoPlayer);
release(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь требуется уточнить, какой именно результат работы программы не удовлетворяет требованиям. Основываясь только на теле программы, можно предположить, что hold off не дает требуемого результата, ибо в каждом проходе проходе цикла обработки и отображения перед geoplot находится hold on. Т.е. Вы закрываете оси от отрисовки поверх имеющихся данных, но перед каждой отрисовкой все равно открываете. Или же hold off должен остаться после исчерпания входных данных (isDone) для последующей части кода, которая здесь не приведена? В таком случае удобнее разместить hold off один раз после цикла, чем каждый раз "дергать рубильник" туда-сюда).

Comment: дело в том что я пытаюсь подставить frame2 , функцию после кода hold off уже объединённую вместе, но к сожалению не удаётся, не знаю за какую функцию взять чтобы  frame2  работал вместе с hold on

Comment: если ставить hold off после цикла, то видео на выходе идёт такое, как будто не применяется функция hold. Функция hold определяет точку, выделяет объект , покадрово он это делает и на изображении , а вот с видео нет